# Как ограничить ввод строки?

Tags: c

С помощью `scanf` ввожу строку. При этом нужно, чтобы ввелось не более 10 символов. С `printf`, например, работает такое:

```
printw("%*s", size, name);
```

но с `scnaf` так не получается. Только если ввожу непосредственно число в спецификатор:

```
scanf("%10s", name);
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой GNU Readline там есть возможность гибкой настройки.

Comment: Проблема в том, что scanf может читать данные в несколько переменных сразу одной командой `scanf("%d%d", &r, &с);`. Ограничением буферов как раз и являются цифры после %. Возможно это не то решение, которое вы ищете, но можно формировать строку `"%10s"` динамически в зависимости от размера буфера. Или сделать обертку над scanf, которая будет принимать параметры парами (переменная, размер)

Comment: http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/fgets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято [оттуда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25410835/1892060):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRLEN_(x) #x
#define STRLEN(x) STRLEN_(x)

#define LEN 8

int main(void)
{
    char s[LEN];
    scanf("%" STRLEN(LEN) "s", s);
    printf("%*s\n", LEN, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Альтернативный вариант - создавать строку формата динамически. Встроенного метода в стандартной библиотеке похоже нет.

Comment: то что надо. СПС!